# Разная запись объявления и определения функции-члена класса

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, code-style

Можно ли по-разному записывать объявление и определение шаблонного класса?

Например, есть класс:

```
template<class T> 
struct A {
    using value_type = T;    
    
    value_type foo() const;
};
```

Можно ли определить его функцию-член как:

```
template<class T>
auto A<T>::foo() const -> value_type {
    return 42;
}
```

чтобы не писать такое длинное определение:

```
template<class T>
typename A<T>::value_type A<T>::foo() const {
    return 42;
}
```

Если можно, то считается ли это нормальным стилем C++ программирования или лучше чтобы всё было в 1 стиле написания? Как лучше всего записывать подобные длинные определения в целом?

Comment: Лучше записывать сразу в теле класса, а выносить наружу только при необходимости. Но само расположения возвращаемого типа - в начале или в конце - не принципиально, так что можно делать как сподручнее.

Comment: @user7860670 *Лучше записывать сразу в теле класса* - а как же разделение объявлений и определений? Определения у меня в другом файле, если что.

Comment: Если в .cpp-файле - вы таки будете иметь неприятностей при линковке...

Comment: @Harry нет, специальный файл для шаблонных определений, включаемый в `.hpp` с объявлением класса

Comment: А у вас есть *необходимость* в разделении определения и объявления? Это же делать совсем не обязательно, причем даже для не шаблонных классов.

Comment: @user7860670 необходимости нет, но для читаемости лучше

Comment: как  это лучше, когда определение будет в другом месте, да еще и с повторением, причем в любом случае более длинным, сигнатуры функции и параметров шаблона?

Comment: @user7860670 потому что пользователь класса может зайти в `.hpp` и увидеть интерфейс, предоставляемый классом, не заботять о деталях реализации = определениях функций. Точно так же как и с разделением обычных классов на `.hpp` и `.cpp`.

Comment: он и без вынесения определений наружу так сможет сделать... Разделение обычных классов на .hpp и .cpp тоже обычно не нужно. Плодить единицы трасляции без необходимости - дурная практика.

Comment: @user7860670 а как тогда использовать класс в разных единицах трансляции, если не выносить отдельно объявления?

Comment: Опять же, выносить определения наружу - только при необходимости. Создавать новую единицу трансляции для этих определений - тоже только при необходимости. Обычно большую часть кода можно реализовать прямо в теле класса, а выносить наружу когда имеются циклические зависимости, а единицу трансляции создавать только в особых случаях (например когда необходимо ограничить видимость какой-то сторонней библиотеки, требующей особых препроцессорных директив или еще какие-то выкрутасы).

Comment: *"пользователь класса может зайти в .hpp и увидеть интерфейс, предоставляемый классом, не заботять о деталях реализации"* Если IDE умеет сворачивать фигурные скобки, то это не проблема.

Answer (score 0):

"Можно ли по-разному записывать объявление и определение шаблонного класса?" - можно.

"Если можно, то считается ли это нормальным стилем C++ программирования или лучше чтобы всё было в 1 стиле написания? Как лучше всего записывать подобные длинные определения в целом?" - нормально, хотя обычно придерживаются одного стиля.